# Prometheus: how to rate a sum of the same counter from different machines?

Tags: sum, prometheus, rate

I have a Prometheus counter, for which I want to get its **rate** on a time range (the real target is to **sum** the **rate**, and sometimes use **histogram_quantile** on that for histogram metric).
However, I've got multiple machines running that kind of job, each one sets its own **instance** label. This causes different **inc** operations on this counter in different machines to create different entities of the counter, as the combination of labels values is unique.
The problem is that **rate()** works separately on each such counter entity.
The result is that counter entities with unique combinations don't get into account for **rate()**.
For example, if I've got:

```
mycounter{aaa="1",instance="1.2.3.4:6666",job="job1"} value: 1
mycounter{aaa="2",instance="1.2.3.4:6666",job="job1"} value: 1
mycounter{aaa="2",instance="1.2.3.4:7777",job="job1"} value: 1
mycounter{aaa="1",instance="5.5.5.5:6666",job="job1"} value: 1
```

All counter entities are unique, so they get values of 1.
If counter labels are always unique (come from different machines), **rate(mycounter[5m])** would get values of 0 in this case,
and **sum(rate(mycounter[5m]))** would get 0, which is not what I need!
I want to ignore the **instance** label so that it would refer these mycounter **inc** operations as they were made on the same counter entity.
In other words, I expect to have only 2 entities (they can have a common **instance** value or no **instance** label):

```
mycounter{aaa="1", job="job1"} value: 2
mycounter{aaa="2", job="job1"} value: 2
```

In such a case, **inc** operation in new machine (with existing **aaa** value) would increase some entity counter instead of adding new entity with value of 1, and **rate()** would get real rates for each, so we may **sum()** them. 
How do I do that?

I made several tries to solve it but all failed:

- Doing a **rate()** of the **sum()** -  fails because of type mismatch...
- Removing the automatic **instance** label, using **metric_relabel_configswork** with **action: labeldrop** in configuration, but then it assigns the default address value.
- Changing all **instance** values to a common one using **metric_relabel_configswork** with **replacement**, but it seems that one of the entities overwrites all others, so it doesn't help...

Any suggestions?

**Prometheus version: 2.3.2**
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4):

You'd better expose your counters at 0 on application start, if the other labels (`aaa`, etc) have a limited set of possible combinations. This way `rate()` function works correctly at the bottom level and `sum()` will give you correct results.

If you have to do a `rate()` of the `sum()`, read [this](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#rate) first:

> Note that when combining `rate()` with an aggregation operator (e.g. `sum()`) or a function aggregating over time (any function ending in `_over_time`), always take a `rate()` first, then aggregate. Otherwise `rate()` cannot detect counter resets when your target restarts.

If you can tolerate this (or the instances reset counters at the same time), there's a way to work around. Define a [recording rule](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/recording_rules/) as

```
record: job:mycounter:sum
expr: sum without(instance) (mycounter)
```

and then this expression works:

```
sum(rate(job:mycounter:sum[5m]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious query `rate(sum(...))` won't work in most cases, since the resulting `sum(...)` may hide possible resets to zero for individual time series, which are passed to `sum`. So usually the correct answer is to use `sum(rate(...))` instead. See [this article](https://www.robustperception.io/rate-then-sum-never-sum-then-rate) for details.

Unfortunately, Prometheus may miss some increases for slow-changing counter when calculating `rate()` as shown in the original question above. The same applies to `increase()` calculations. See [this issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746), [this comment](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/issues/1215#issuecomment-850305711) and [this article](https://medium.com/@romanhavronenko/victoriametrics-promql-compliance-d4318203f51e) for details. Prometheus developers are going to fix these issues - see [this design doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1y2Mp041_2v0blnKnZk7keCnJZICeK2YWUQuXH_m4DVc/edit).

In the mean time try to use [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) when you need exact values for [rate()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rate) and [increase()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) functions over slow-changing counter (and distributed counter).